# How to prevent BYO devices connecting to AD domain

Tags: active-directory, group-policy, windows-domain, kerberos, domain-security

My client has a computer lab several with Windows 10 PCs connected via ethernet to the company's active directory domain. each individual at the company has their own credentials with which to login.

I want to restrict people from using their valid credentials to access domain resources from their nonjoined(personal) devices (e.g. laptops). They're welcome to use the ethernet to connect to the network and internet, but not to connect to the AD domain.

Answer (score 1):

IPSEC should be the best solution.

Configure your Domain server to "**Require authentication for inbound and outbound connections**" (IPSEC) on port 445 (you do this through the GPO). Specify custom first and second authentication method as COMPUTER and USER, and use "Domain Computers" as the computer authentication group.

On CLIENT(Domain joined) machines, all of them(all of those that need to access those resources), set a corresponding IPSEC rule (again through GPO) stating ""**Request authentication for inbound and outbound connections**"

> Clients should not require inbound connections to be authenticated – they just must be able to initiate secure outbound connections (servers that require inbound authentication will respond with IPsec while all other hosts will reply as usually)

This setup will force the device from which the connection is initialized to authenticate itself, and by doing so, accessing domain resources from non-domain joined devices will be forbidden. Everything else will work, as usual, normal Share/NTFS permissions will still apply in the same manner they did without the IPSEC rule, so you can set the IPSEC rule to use "Domain Computers" and "Domain Users" without major issues.

Here is some reasonably good [how to do this](https://michaelfirsov.wordpress.com/implemeting-ipsec-in-windows-domain-part-1/). Although, You will have to tweak it for your case.

Comment: We have more than 10 machines which any authorized personnel may use. I'd like only authorized devices to be accepted into the domain. i.e. no personal devices brought from home. it's not about the number of machines, it's about not allowing unvetted machines into the enterprise domain.

Comment: I gave You the solution for that. If there are just specific people which can join devices to the domain, you can control which devices are added and which are not. Or maybe you wanna forbid them to access domain resources from their nonjoined devices by utilizing their domain credentials – like- I’ve brought from home my non-domain laptop and with my VOICES\LESHY acc I have access to “VOICES-FS-01/ENTERPRISESHARE” which is domain share inside “VOICES.LOCAL” domain, I just have to type my leshy@voices.local acc credentials?

Comment: yes the latter sounds correct.

Comment: I have edited my Answer.